# Multiple Selection Of Image in iOS

Tags: ios

hey I'm new in iOS app developing world...

I had open the gallery and selected only one image and displayed on image view.

Now I want to select multiple image from Gallery.

So my question is

How should I select multiple image from Gallery in iOS and display on UIImageView???

Comment: Parag If my answer is helpful for you please tick my answer.Because others can see and utilize your question and my answer.

Comment: If i don't want used any other 3rd party. There is any other way to select multiple images without using ELCImagePickerController or any other 3rd party

Comment: This is the perfect way to do this than other  3rd party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you should not pick multiple images from iOS native picker so
from `UIImagePickerController` you can get only one picture. If you need to pick more you need a custom image picker, such as **ELCImagePickerController**. It works well! You can download it [here](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController).

Answer (score 2):

`UIImagePickerController` doesn't support multiple selection by default, but you can use libraries like [`QBImagePicker`](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePicker) to achieve that.